# Adding historical events to iOS7 calendar

Tags: ios7, calendar

I just ran into an issue that took me a while to solve and hadn't seen it mentioned on SO, so here it is. I was just trying to programmatically add events to my calendar that are over 1 month old and on iOS7 (not iOS6) these events would not show up in a calendar, and neither were they available when I did a (programatic) query of the calendar. Adding events with future dates or dates up to 1 month in the past worked fine.

Here is the code I am using to add the event:

```
EKEvent *newCalendarEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

// In seconds; one hour default duration.
#define DURATION_OF_EVENT 60*60

newCalendarEvent.startDate = self.date;
// If I just use the startDate as the end date, then the height of the event in the calendar is really short.
NSDate *endEventDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:DURATION_OF_EVENT sinceDate:self.date];
newCalendarEvent.endDate = endEventDate;

newCalendarEvent.title = [self getEventTitle];
newCalendarEvent.calendar = cal;
NSError *error = nil;
[eventStore saveEvent:newCalendarEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"CalendarIntegration.integrateDate: Error saving event: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: No error messages? Just blindly failing? It might be more helpful for others if you show what code or methods you use to create the calendar entry.

Comment: I added some above. Let me know if you want more. Yes, just blindly "failing". Failing in the sense that the calendar doesn't show the events. It *does* however show the events once you change the Settings app as described below.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this seems to be a side effect of iOS7's Setting app setting under Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Synch. My setting was 1 month. By changing it to 3 months, I was able to create events up to 3 months old *and* have them displayed in the calendar. Note that I am talking about the calendar on the device that created the calendar event, in which case, I can't see how calendar synch would apply. But apparently, not all (e.g., Apple) would agree with this.